# Exception similar to ModuleNotFoundError in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, error-handling, exception

I'm trying to add some explicit exceptions to a piece of code, but the problem is that I have Python 3 and it has to be Python 2.7 compatible with the `ModuleNotFoundError` in Python 3. So any which exception is similar to that in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `ImportError`. `ModuleNotFoundError` is a subclass of `ImportError`, and a very new one, having only been introduced in Python 3.6.

If you want to use `ModuleNotFoundError` when it's available and `ImportError` if it's not, you can make a feature check:

```
try:
    ModuleNotFoundError
except NameError:
    ModuleNotFoundError = ImportError

# later
raise ModuleNotFoundError(whatever_message)
```